# Minimizing the largest eigenvalue in a family of nonnegative matrices.

Tags: symmetric-matrices

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of symmetric, nonnegative matrices of order $n$ whose diagonal entries are zero. Let $\rho(A)$ be the largest eigenvalue of $A$. Suppose $\min\{\rho(A):A\in \mathcal{F}\}=\rho(B).$

Now consider a new family $\mathcal{S}=\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}A&x\\x^T&0\end{array}\right): A\in \mathcal{F} , x=(0,0,\dots,0,2)\}$. If we want to get minimum over the largest eigenvalues of matrices in $\mathcal{S}$. Then how to proceed. I started with calculating characteristic polynomial of a matrix in $\mathcal{S}$ and but could not relate it to the characteristic polynomial of a matrix in $\mathcal{F}.$

Any suggestion please?

Comment: what does "symmetric, nonnegative" mean? real SPSD?  or real symmetric with non-negative components?

Comment: It means real symmetric with nonnegative entries.